# Как убрать лишние края вокруг изображения в QListWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qlistwidget, qstackedwidget

Кнопка `btn` не выполняет никаких функций. Я добавил ее, т.к. в окне будут и другие элементы, т.е. мне нужно видеть, как `QListWidget + QStackedWidget` будут расположены, если окажутся не одни в приложении.

Проблема этого кода в том, что изображение, попадающее в `QListWidget`, почему-то уменьшается и располагается у левой границы виджета:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне бы хотелось, чтобы изображение принимало размер примерно **40px*40px**, а размер `QListWidget` определялся размером изображения(т.е. чтобы не было рамки):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как это можно сделать?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class LeftTabWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LeftTabWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resize(400, 300)

        layout1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
        layout1.addWidget(btn)

        layout2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(spacing=0)
        layout2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout1.addLayout(layout2)

        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self)
        layout2.addWidget(self.listWidget)

        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self)
        layout2.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)

        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):

        self.listWidget.currentRowChanged.connect(self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex)

        self.listWidget.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QListWidget.NoFrame)
        self.listWidget.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.listWidget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        for i in range(2):
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(QtGui.QIcon('play.png'), '', self.listWidget)
            item.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(60, 60))

        for i in range(2):
            label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Страница %d' % (i + 1), self)
            label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            label.setStyleSheet('background: #7189DB; margin: 0px;')
            self.stackedWidget.addWidget(label)


Stylesheet = '''
QListWidget, QListView, QTreeWidget, QTreeView {
    outline: 0px;
}
QListWidget::item:selected {
    background: #7189DB;
}
HistoryPanel::item:hover {background: rgb(52, 52, 52);}
QStackedWidget {background: rgb(30, 30, 30);}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)
    w = LeftTabWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я немного изменил код и оставил цветовую палитру, чтобы вы увидели что есть что, измените как вам надо.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class LeftTabWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LeftTabWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setMinimumSize(500, 300)

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
        layout1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout1.addWidget(btn)

        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.listWidget.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0) 
        self.listWidget.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.IconMode)
        self.listWidget.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 60))
        self.listWidget.setMovement(QtWidgets.QListView.Static)
        self.listWidget.setMaximumWidth(61)
        self.listWidget.setMinimumWidth(61)
        self.listWidget.setSpacing(0)  

        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        for i in range(2):
            label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Страница %d' % (i + 1), self)
            label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
#            label.setStyleSheet('background: #7189DB; margin: 0px;')
            self.stackedWidget.addWidget(label)

        self.createIcons()
        self.listWidget.setCurrentRow(0)

        layout2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(spacing=0) 
        layout2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout2.addWidget(self.listWidget)              
        layout2.addWidget(self.stackedWidget, 1)                       # !!! stretch=1
        layout1.addLayout(layout2)

    def createIcons(self):
        configButton = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self.listWidget)
        configButton.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('play.png'))
#        configButton.setText("")
        configButton.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        configButton.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)

        updateButton = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self.listWidget)
        updateButton.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('play.png'))
#        updateButton.setText("")
        updateButton.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        updateButton.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)

        self.listWidget.currentItemChanged.connect(self.changePage)

    def changePage(self, current, previous):
        if not current:
            current = previous
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(self.listWidget.row(current))



Stylesheet = '''
QListWidget {
    border: none;
    background-color: #ff0;      
}
QListWidget::item {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    color: #3b4155;
}
QListWidget::item:hover {
    background-color: #f0f;
}

QListWidget::item:selected {
    background-color: #0ff;
}

QLabel {
    background: #FF3333; 
    margin: 0px;
    color: white;
    font: 21pt;
}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)
    w = LeftTabWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое! Это практически то, что мне нужно. Но есть еще одна штука, которая меня тревожит. Могу ли я создать новый вопрос по поводу вашего кода?

Comment: С таким я никогда не сталкивался и рабочую формулировку для поиска в гугле придумать не могу:(

Comment: @MAXIM045 этот сайт для того и существует чтобы задавать вопросы. Я бы сформулировал новый вопрос так, основываясь на ответе на мой (т.е. ваш) предыдущий вопрос, пытаюсь сделать то-то и то-то, но получается так-то. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Ничего, что практически весь код будет вашим?:) Но исправить ситуацию я то же пытался(не помогло)

Comment: @MAXIM045 не пишите о том где и чей код, все это из общедоступного доступа. Вы пишите приложение и ответственность берете на себя.